# what are your favourite subversion tips and tricks

Tags: svn

Subversion is my source control of choice after experience with source safe and subversion.

Developing with .net I find the commit dialog cluttered with files that are not relevant and should be ignored.  Since v1.5, ignoring patterns of files and folders is a life saver to help prevent missing files that I should be checking in.

Another tip I find useful is adding external assembly binaries with a "Latest" version folder:

```
 Repo A
  - Proj1
  - Lib(External retrieves latest binary of Repo B)

 Repo B (Library)
   - Proj1 
   - Proj2
   - Binaries
     - v1
     - Latest
```

That way, when I do an update, I get the latest external assemblies too.

What tips and tricks do you have for making life with Subversion easier and as a developer?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294256/favorite-non-obvious-feature-of-svn/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/).

Answer (score 2):

It's great to be able to use sparse checkouts, where bulky uninteresting directories can be skipped: http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2009/03/sparse-directories-now-with-exclusion.html